# why is mongodb hitting this index

Tags: mongodb

Given that i have an index in my collection **asd**

```
> db.system.indexes.find().pretty()
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "asd.test", "name" : "_id_" },
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "a" : 1,
                "b" : 1,
                "c" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "asd.test",
        "name" : "a_1_b_1_c_1"
}
```

As far as i know in theory the order of the parameters queried is important in order to hit an index...

That is why im wondering how and why im actually hitting the index with this query

```
> db.asd.find({c:{$gt: 5000},a:{$gt:5000}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1_b_1_c_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 90183,
        "nscannedObjects" : 90183,
        "nscanned" : 94885,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 90288,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 94990,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 1,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 272,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "a" : [
                        [
                                5000,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ],
                "b" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "c" : [
                        [
                                5000,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is important in `mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

Order in which you pass fields in your query does not affect index selection process. If it did, it'd be a very fragile system.

Order of fields in the index definition, on the other hand, is very important. Maybe you confuse these two cases.

Comment: ahh ofc, that explains the behavior